# Overriding WPF UserControl default theme

Tags: wpf, themes, resourcedictionary, wpf-4.0, mahapps.metro

I'm using `MahApps.Metro` in a WPF project. But instead of using the nuget package, I download the source code and add it as a project to my solution (for some reasons). As you know, it has a default theme for all it's controls. Now, I'm trying to change the default them of `MetroWindow` in my project. I don't want to change the original projects. So I have created a new `ResourceDictionary` and I'm styling in that. I tried to change `MetroWindow` default them, but it seems it's not possible without having a `x:Key` attribute. I mean I tried this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type metro:MetroWindow}">
    <!-- My styles and templates gone here... -->
</Style>
```

and this one too:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type metro:MetroWindow}" TargetType="{x:Type metro:MetroWindow}">
    <!-- My styles and templates gone here... -->
</Style>
```

But none of them, make effects on control and the control still is using the default theme defined by `MahApps.Metro`. What I missed? Any idea? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have also tried the same but it turns out that it is not possible to change the window style that way. The only way you can do it is by [rolling your own window](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/#roll_your_own_window).

As for the controls, you can change the style by using eg:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroButton}">
    <!-- your changes here -->
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is to create your own theme.

1. Copy the content of the BaseLight.xaml or the BaseDark.xaml file from Mahapps and paste it in your new theme file.
2. Override the theme at application startup

   ```
   protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
   {
       base.OnStartup(e);

       // Add and apply style
       ThemeManager.AddAccent("CustomAccent", new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Custom.Style;component/CustomAccent.xaml"));
       ThemeManager.AddAppTheme("CustomTheme", new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Customo.Style;component/CustomTheme.xaml"));
       ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle(Application.Current, ThemeManager.GetAccent("CustomAccent"), ThemeManager.GetAppTheme("CustomTheme"));
   }
   ```
3. To change the background color of all MetroWindow for example, change the value of the key "WhiteColor"